# How to save docker manifest file to tar file

Tags: docker

I have a docker application/vnd.docker.distribution.manifest.v2+json file. Is it possible or any way to docker save it as a tar file?

Comment: That's a JSON file that just has a list of layers and metadata, but not any of the image content itself?

Comment: @DavidMaze correct me if i am wrong, to get the image, i need to do docker pull this json file?